# Lifting snp rsid build 37 to 38

Tags: gwas, identifiers, liftover

I’m looking to lift over a dataset of GWAS summary stats from build 37 to 38, including converting rsid. Downstream it is to be used for co-localisation with another dataset of build 38.

Would anyone be able to help with code for doing this please?

Comment: Have you tried some tool or approach already?

Comment: Should we assume you are working on human data? Are the SNPs in coding regions only or do you also have intronic or, even worse, intergenic? Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Ideally also an example of your input.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple tools to use for this. Might I suggest the following reads: [Introduction to liftover tools](https://genviz.org/module-01-intro/0001/06/02/liftoverTools/), where they also refer to this usefull post [BioStars post](https://www.biostars.org/p/65558/). Maybe also consider reading this paper for a word of caution: [Paper](https://academic.oup.com/bib/article/22/5/bbab069/6210068?login=true).

Maybe you can also clarify you question more, if these links do not help you with what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently worked on a couple of [tools](https://github.com/freeseek/score) to do exactly this. They are +munge to convert summary statistics into files following the [GWAS-VCF specification](https://github.com/MRCIEU/gwas-vcf-specification) and +liftover to convert a VCF from one genome build to another. This will automatically take care of REF⇆ALT switches by flipping the effect size and it will correctly handle indels, if there are any, in your summary statistics file